# Fitting a curve and interpolating in Matlab

Tags: matlab, curve-fitting

I have a dataset and I want to fit a curve. The original dataset contains values from 3500 to 4100 with steps of 1.67. I then want to use the fitted curve and find the y2 values for some other x2 values (e.g. 300 more x2 data). How can I do this in matlab?

[image]

Comment: Do you want to fit a line and interpolate? What sort of curve do you want to fit?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As your plot looks like a simple linear interpolation, you could use

```
fitfun=@(x) interp1(x2,y2,x,'linear');
```

to define a function `fitfun(x)`. Then just call this function with your new `x2` values, I think it should work directly with the array (the result will be an array of the same size):

```
newy2=fitfun(newx2);
```

Watch out for the bounds: interpolation can't give you points outside the domain set by `x2`, unless you tell it what to say (default out-of-bounds value is `NaN`, I think)

Comment: Sorry for this simple question, but how should I call the created function using my new data (x1)?

Comment: Just do  `y1 = fitfun(x1)`.

Comment: Sam: exactly what @sodiumnitrate said. Edited my answer for completeness.